# struts2 token error struts.token and struts.token.name

Tags: java, struts2

i was testing differents scenaries for the token and have this problem, when i use:

```
<action name="sincronizar" class="action.SincronizarAction">
        <interceptor-ref name="token"/>
        <interceptor-ref name="mystack"/>   
        <result name="success" type="tiles">d_sincronizar</result>
        <result name="input" type="tiles">d_sincronizar</result>
        <result name="invalid.token" type="tiles">d_sincronizar</result>
    </action>
```

have this error in console:

```
WARNING: Error setting expression 'struts.token' with value '[Ljava.lang.String;@3584de'
ognl.OgnlException: target is null for setProperty(null, "token",      
[Ljava.lang.String;@3584de)
at ognl.OgnlRuntime.setProperty(OgnlRuntime.java:2312)
at ognl.ASTProperty.setValueBody(ASTProperty.java:127)
```

now i remake with "basicStack":

```
<action name="sincronizar" class="action.SincronizarAction">
        <interceptor-ref name="token"/>
        <interceptor-ref name="basicStack"/>    
        <result name="success" type="tiles">d_sincronizar</result>
        <result name="input" type="tiles">d_sincronizar</result>
        <result name="invalid.token" type="tiles">d_sincronizar</result>
    </action>
```

and not problem. but i need to use my stack. Additional when i make new stack with same interceptors get the same problem. Example: lowStack same basicStack http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/interceptors.html

```
<interceptor-stack name="lowStack">
            <interceptor-ref name="exception"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="servletConfig"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="prepare"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="checkbox"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="multiselect"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="actionMappingParams"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="params"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="conversionError"/>
     </interceptor-stack>

<action name="sincronizar" class="action.SincronizarAction">
        <interceptor-ref name="token"/>
        <interceptor-ref name="lowStack"/>  
        <result name="success" type="tiles">d_sincronizar</result>
        <result name="input" type="tiles">d_sincronizar</result>
        <result name="invalid.token" type="tiles">d_sincronizar</result>
    </action>
```

I have the same problem.

Comment: In your `myStack` do you set the value of `invalid.token`?

Comment: invalid.token is generated when the interceptor-token detecte the problem of same submit(double click in submit or F5 in page).

Comment: Sorry, I meant `struts.token` - it looks like you are trying to set the value of that as an OGNL expression rather than a `String`.

Comment: In my form i have the tag <s:token/> this generate tow fields of text hidden for check the tokens, with the name struts.token and struts.token.name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is happening because you are missing the `excludeParams` parameter for the `params` interceptor.
It should look something like that:

```
<interceptor-ref name="params">
  <param name="excludeParams">dojo\..*,^struts\..*,^session\..*,^request\..*,^application\..*,^servlet(Request|Response)\..*,parameters\...*</param>
</interceptor-ref>
```

Take a look at the [`struts-default.xml`](http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/struts-defaultxml.html) where `basicStack` interceptor is defined.

Answer (score 1):

Old question but I ran into this problem and the excludeParams didn't work. When testing my app the double submit on forms was still an issue.

Solution to the problem is thinking about the message a bit deeper. Struts is trying to set the value, it doesn't mean on the form, it means in the action controller java object. So simply add a set/get for String token.

In the action class add:

```
String token;
public void setToken(String token) { this.token = token; }
public String getToken() { return token; }
```

Pretty sure that's the problem. Using an exclude param just hides it preventing the interceptor from trying to access missing methods in the code base.

Some good information about this here too:

http://www.journaldev.com/2281/struts2-token-interceptor-to-handle-double-form-submission-problem#comment-30355

I posted some comments to expand on his tutorial, waiting for moderator to approve before they can be seen at the moment though.

Comment: This answer was, actually, the right one for my case. Thanks Sir!!